# django admin override filter_horizontal

Tags: django, django-admin, django-admin-filters

I'm aiming to make an "advanced" filter_horizontal, one with more filters, but I can't seem to find the widget to override.
I know it uses the related_widget_wrapper.html, but if I want to add functionalities to it in a clear way, what is the widget to override.

For now my backup solution is to do a full javascript solution to prepend it with a dropdown on form load (created from javascript) and make ajax calls to modify the filter...but this seems as an overkill.

What i've done so far :

```
# Override filteredSelectMultiple, add javascript and add attributes on the tag to identify the element, and add parameter url that will contain the ajax call
class AjaxFilterHorizontalWidget(FilteredSelectMultiple):

    def __init__(self, url, verbose_name = '', is_stacked=False, attrs=None, choices=()):
        self.url = url
        super().__init__(verbose_name, is_stacked, attrs, choices)

    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context['widget']['attrs']['data-url'] = self.url
        context['widget']['attrs']['data-ajax-select'] = '1'
        return context



    class Media:
        js = ['admin/js/ajax_filter_horizontal.js']
```

Ajax_filter_horizontal.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[data-ajax-select=1]').each(function (index, item) {
        var currentRequest;
        var url = $(item).data('url')
        // var wrapper = $('#' + $(item).prop('id')).closest('.selector-available')
        $(document).on('keyup', $('.selector-filter input'), function () {
            if ($('.selector-filter input').val().length < 3) {
                $(item).empty()
                return
            }
            currentRequest = $.ajax({
                url: url,
                data: {q: $('.selector-filter input').val()},
                beforeSend : function()    {
                    if(currentRequest != null) {
                        currentRequest.abort();
                    }
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $(item).empty()
                    let item_to = $('#' + $(item).prop('id').replace('_from', '_to'))
                    if (data.results.length > 500) {
                        $('#' + $(item).prop('id')).append('<option disabled value="" title="">Too many results, refine your search...</option>')
                        return
                    }

                    for (let instance of data.results) {
                        if ($('option[value='+instance.id+']', item_to).length == 0) {
                            $('#' + $(item).prop('id')).append('<option value="'+instance.id+'" title="'+instance.text+'">'+instance.text+'</option>')
                        }
                    }

                    SelectBox.init($(item).prop('id'))
                }
            })
        });
    });
});
```

I had to override the field, just to remove validation(for some reason the validation is also done on the original values, the left side of the filter_horizontal)

```
class AjaxMultipleChoiceField(MultipleChoiceField):
    widget = AjaxFilterHorizontalWidget

    def validate(self, value):
        pass
        """Validate that the input is a list or tuple."""
        # if self.required and not value:
        #     raise ValidationError(self.error_messages['required'], code='required')
```

This is how I call it :

```
    self.fields['person'] = `AjaxMultipleChoiceField(widget=AjaxFilterHorizontalWidget(url= '/person-autocomplete-advanced/', verbose_name='People to invite'))`
```

I can't manage to find where to prefill the values in the "to" section when I'm editing an existing field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django Model admin overrides `BaseModelAdmin` which contains following code.

**django.contrib.admin.options.py**

```py
class BaseModelAdmin(six.with_metaclass(forms.MediaDefiningClass)):
    ...
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        ...
        if db_field.name in self.raw_id_fields:
            kwargs['widget'] = widgets.ManyToManyRawIdWidget(db_field.remote_field, self.admin_site, using=db)
        elif db_field.name in (list(self.filter_vertical) + list(self.filter_horizontal)):
            kwargs['widget'] = widgets.FilteredSelectMultiple(
                db_field.verbose_name,
                db_field.name in self.filter_vertical
            )
```

It can be observed that if there is `filter_vertical` or `filter_horizontal` argument passed 
in `ModelAdmin` option than it adds `FilteredSelectMultiple` widget.

Below is the source of `FilteredSelectMultiple` You may override this if necessary

**django.contrib.admin.widgets.py**

```py
class FilteredSelectMultiple(forms.SelectMultiple):
    """
    A SelectMultiple with a JavaScript filter interface.

    Note that the resulting JavaScript assumes that the jsi18n
    catalog has been loaded in the page
    """
    @property
    def media(self):     # override this property in your custom class
        js = ["core.js", "SelectBox.js", "SelectFilter2.js"]
        return forms.Media(js=["admin/js/%s" % path for path in js])
    ...
    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        context = super(FilteredSelectMultiple, self).get_context(name, value, attrs)
        context['widget']['attrs']['class'] = 'selectfilter'
        if self.is_stacked:
            context['widget']['attrs']['class'] += 'stacked'
        context['widget']['attrs']['data-field-name'] = self.verbose_name
        context['widget']['attrs']['data-is-stacked'] = int(self.is_stacked)
        return context
```

**For JS or Media overriding**

You could observe that `media` property on `FilteredSelectMultiple` class have several js included you may modify them as per your needs.

**For HTML template modifications**

`FilteredSelectMultiple` overrides `django.forms.widgets.SelectMultiple` which ultimately overrides `django.forms.widgets.Select` widget.

So it can be said that `FilteredSelectMultiple` uses following properties of `Select` widget

```
class Select(ChoiceWidget):
    input_type = 'select'
    template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/select.html'
    option_template_name = 'django/forms/widgets/select_option.html'
    add_id_index = False
    checked_attribute = {'selected': True}
    option_inherits_attrs = False
    ...
```

You can override those options inside your `FilteredSelectMultiple` class.

I hope the information above is useful for you.

Comment: Thank you, this is what i opted for in the end.

Comment: I prepared a custom widget called AjaxFitlerHorizontal, just have a couple of questions : Where to define the queryset to be empty on init () and the values to be set when we're editing a form ?

Comment: Could you please attach `AjaxFitlerHorizontal` with your question or in separate question?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I added my code to the question, I don't if what i took is the right approach, since it's mainly javascript side.