# How to change django filter_horizontal filter parammeter

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to add product to category model in admin page.

models.py

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Categorymodels.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category_product = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True, related_name='category_product')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.promo_name
```

admin.py

```py
@admin.register(Category)
class CategoryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('category_product', )
    pass
```

When adding products to category, I can use filtering but it filters only by product name.
How do I filter something else.

Comment: Maybe This will helpfull
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55472737/7122788

Comment: Does it matter if it is drf?

Comment: @Parca what other thing you want to filter? the manytomany filter will filter by the __str__() method in your related model

Comment: @LinhNguyen ohhhh I got. Thank you!!!!!